# How to get facebook page access_token and use it for webhook leadgen return?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, webhooks

I am using webhooks on lead generation on facebook (PHP Back-END). I have done the tutorial in which they explain how these leads can be retrieved.

I've tested my code and everything works perfectly, except for the fact that my `access_token` is hard-coded and I want to retrieve it on every request.

I am using this code to access the facebook graph:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url
));
```

the url looks like this:

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/' . $leadgen_id . '?access_token=' . $access_token . '&debug=all&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1';
```

How can I have the access token **automatically**, every time the webhook script is called?

Comment: Were you able to figure out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate and store an "Extended Page Token", it is valid forever. There is no way to generate Tokens automatically.

The general procedure:

- Get a User Token with `manage_pages`
- Extend the User Token
- Get an Extended Page Token with `/me/accounts`

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Update: there are new permissions now, replacing `manage_pages`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/overview#permissions

Comment: Hello @luschn, your answer is still valid today?

Comment: in general, yes - but manage_pages gut replaced by other permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/overview#permissions